# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: PythonVirtualenvOperator requires virtualenv, please install it

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, ubuntu-18.04

I set up my airflow using pypi. An error occurred after start the airflow server by below command:
airflow standalone

airflow_version == 2.2.0

python_version == 3.8.4

but i have installed virtualenv.

Exception as below:

```
  Broken DAG: [/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site- 
  packages/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py] Traceback 
  (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site- 
  packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 188, in apply_defaults
  result = func(self,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site- 
  packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 342, in __init__
  raise AirflowException('PythonVirtualenvOperator requires virtualenv, 
  please install it.')
  airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: PythonVirtualenvOperator requires 
  virtualenv, please install it
```

I have no idea to fix the bug, don't know what's wrong happen.

thank everyone very much!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue running this in Google Cloud Build when trying to upgrade Airflow.

On closer inpection, it looks like Airflow uses the `which` command to check if `virtualenv` exists. Because we were using `pip install virtualenv --user` to persist package installations between build steps, we needed to add `export PATH="/builder/home/.local/bin:$$PATH"` to our build script.

To see if this will work for you:

1. after install run `which virtualenv` to see if it finds the virtualenv command
2. if it doesn't, add the folder that `virtualenv` was installed in to your PATH and try starting the Airflow server again

Answer (score 0):

You need to install virtualenv package on the machine.

Comment: I have installed virtualenv. there are my code building image.

Comment: https://github.com/AdenLin1993/build_customizing_airflow

Comment: May you need to translate the chinese. Not everyone knows it. ;) 

I cannot see virtualenv being installed in the dockerfile - all you are doing is install airflow. 
https://github.com/AdenLin1993/build_customizing_airflow/blob/main/add_python3.8_pip3/add_airflow2.2/Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you my friend for your suggestion, Now I use English annotations, I'd like you give it a try.   it is normal, when i install airflow 2.1.0 by that dockerfile. but install airflow 2.2.0  happen error.

Comment: nw @aden_lin - You need to install virtualenv to the docker image - that is missing.

Comment: I have install virtualenv, and it is normal to install airflow 2.1.0, https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W379.png